# Code for sorting letters of a word is not working?

Tags: python-3.6

For solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem) question in Hackerrank,I wrote the following piece of code.It worked well on my machine, but when it was submitted,it is evaluated as a wrong answer.

```
T = int(input().strip())
arr = []
result = []

for i in range(T):
    s = input().strip()
    arr.append(s)

for item in arr:
    odd = [];even = []
    for value in item:
        n = item.index(value)
        if n%2 ==0:
            even.append(value)
        if n%2 == 1:
            odd.append(value)
        p = ''.join(even) ; q = ''.join(odd)
    result.append(p + " " + q)
    odd.clear();even.clear();

for value in result:
    print(value)
```

Comment: Your code more or less works for me (except for the index problems pointed out by Anurag Sharma) but since you are reading by `input()` you need to enclose your strings into double quotes. That seems to be in contradiction with the task assigned. Try reading `s` from `raw_input()`. (And your code could be simpler.)

Comment: But raw_input is used in python 2.x not in python 3.x,isn't it?

Comment: I guess you are right about raw_input(); my python is 2.7.14. I had not checked that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this test case:

2

aaB

Baa

Your code is giving wrong results. Inner for loop is looping the characters. What if two characters are same? Your code will give wrong index number.